# Kernel bandwidth for Fisher information estimation

Tags: kernel-smoothing, fisher-information

Suppose $X(\theta)$ and $Y(\theta)$ are two random variables that depend on a parameter $\theta$, and $\sigma_x = \{(x_1,\theta_1), \ldots , (x_n,\theta_n)\}$ and $\sigma_y = \{(y_1,\theta_1), \ldots , (y_n,\theta_n)\}$ are sets of observations of $X$ and $Y$ at various values of $\theta$. I would like to infer from $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ which of the two random variables carries larger amount of Fisher information as a function of $\theta$. To that end, I use Gaussian kernels to infer from $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ the probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and compute the Fisher information as a function of $\theta$ for each variable:

$$\mathcal{I}_k(\theta) = \int \left(\frac{d\,  \textrm{log } f_k(x|\theta)}{d\, \theta}\right)^2f_k(x|\theta)\, dx\qquad k=X,Y$$

where $f_{k}(x|\theta)$ is the (inferred) probability density function of $k$.

The problem I am facing is that $\mathcal{I}_k(\theta)$ strongly depends on the bandwidth of the kernels. How should I choose the bandwidths so that the comparison between $\mathcal{I}_X(\theta)$ and $\mathcal{I}_Y(\theta)$ is informative?